# Using nodejs/crypto in ionic 3 app: decipher.update does not assign the variable value

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic-framework, encryption, electron

I am building an Ionic 3 application for Windows 8.1. This application needs to read NFC Tags using an external NFC reader (connected with USB).
I made a Cordova plugin that gets data between the application and the reader.

My problem is when I want to convert a buffer that I am receiving. I am using "nodejs/crypto" for the following codes:

```
decrypt(key:Buffer, data:Buffer){
    const decipher = createDecipheriv(this._algo, key, this._iv);
    let decryptedBuffer = decipher.update(data);
    return decryptedBuffer;
}

In my case:
- this._algo = 'DES-EDE-CBC'
- key = Buffer.alloc(16).fill(0) 
- this._iv = Buffer.alloc(8).fill(0)
```

When I am using VS 2015 in debug mode, I see the buffer value when I am watching decipher.update(data) but there is nothing when I am watching decryptedBuffer.

I tried this function using Electron framework and it is working. Does anyone have an idea about why my variable is not assigned in Ionic case?